# jenkins error on staring via cmd, using war 2.9

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to start jenkins via command prompt but getting 
jenkins error on  staring via cmd, using war 2.9

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only 1.0 is supported as <?xml version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml version=\'1.1\'... @1:19) 
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDeclWithVersion(MXParser.java:2608)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDecl(MXParser.java:2592)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2466)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1447)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(
```

Answer (score 1):

You have file with invalid XML version, you can replace it using [Jenkins Issue 49450 answer](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49450):

> ran this command in  $JENKINS_HOME:
>
> ```
> find . -name "*.xml" -print -exec sed -i '.bak' "s/xml version='1.1'/xml version='1.0'/" {} \;
> ```